# How to use full-page background image leaving space for binding?

Tags: image, binding, latex, background, wallpaper

In Latex how can you make the background image to occupy the whole sheet on every page *except* a certain stripe on the inner side of each page? I can't figure it out.
I have a background image I'd like to be seen in whole on each page after printing/binding.

Matyi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some rather [scary LaTeX hackery](http://snipplr.com/view/6057/background-image-in-latex/) involving putting a picture environment under every page and using \includegraphics to put an image into that environment.  You'll have to adjust the size of the image using the width option, and if you want even and odd pages you'll have to check the page number to know whether to shift the image right or left by changing \put(0,0) to \put(3,0) for example.

For page number testing try something on the order of

```
\ifodd\count0 ...stuff for odd-numbered pages ...
\else   ... stuff for even-numbered pages ...
\fi
```

This isn't really a full answer but will be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'd just add the white space in the image :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was thinking of something like this.

Is this really so rare need to have? I myself need such a thing for the first time now but I don't feel it a so big oddity. It's strange for me that if you want a background to change over even and odd pages, just like normal text do, you need to feel betraying Latex logics. Or maybe I'm too fanatic of this challenge of mine and I want to feel the whole tex world change to fulfill my wishes. :)


Thank you for the answers!